# Inserting HTML character entities with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a tool that allows me to insert different Spanish characters into a text box such as the inverted question mark. I've currently got the following, but this returns:

```
function (e){var n,r,i,o=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return i=x.isFunction(e),this.each(function(n){var o;1===this.nodeType&&(o=i?e.call(this,n,x(this).val()):e,null==o?o="":"number"==typeof o?o+="":x.isArray(o)&&(o=x.map(o,function(e){return null==e?"":e+""})),r=x.valHooks[this.type]||x.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()],r&&"set"in r&&r.set(this,o,"value")!==t||(this.value=o))});if(o)return r=x.valHooks[o.type]||x.valHooks[o.nodeName.toLowerCase()],r&&"get"in r&&(n=r.get(o,"value"))!==t?n:(n=o.value,"string"==typeof n?n.replace(V,""):null==n?"":n)}}&#191;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<div id="one">&#191;</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#one').click(function() {
    $('#text').val($('#text').val + '&#191;');
});
});
```

Any ideas on why I'm receiving this output? Also do HTML entities work within textboxes, if not how would I do so? No errors appear in the console.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7Yng/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#text").val` is a function, which you are supposed to call.

That said, jQuery is massive overkill for such a trivial task:

```
document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('text').value += "\u00bf";
}
```

Note that `\u00bf` is the appropriate JavaScript escape sequence for ¿ - `bf` being `191` in hexadecimal.

EDIT: Alternatively, just hold Alt and type 0191 on your keypad. This will produce ¿ directly where you are typing, instead of at the end of the input which is what your JS does.

Comment: @mikakun Assuming you have a Spanish keyboard, that is.

Comment: are you assuming spanish speaking people are using english speaking keyboard ? which would be the norm in your opinion ?

Comment: Pretty sure most Mexicans living in the US don't have a ¿ key available. Just an example.

Comment: most Mexicans living in the us & that bought their computer in the us & that didn't switch to spanish keyboard putting new stickers on it, must be about 0.1% of spanish speaking people in the world but there are plenty of other exceptions ! just teasing don't worry

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Worked in your fiddle.

```
$(function() {
    $('#one').on('click', function() {
        $('#text').val($('#text').val() + "¿");
    });
});
```

Update: I posted spanish sign of question instead of its ASCII, changed `$(document).ready` to a shorter way `$(function()`, and added brackets after `val()`.

Comment: Rather than just posting code, it may be a good idea to explain what it is you've changed, why you changed it, and what makes it work now ;)